# Proof that a compact subset of $R^{k}$ is closed by proving that its complement is open

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

I am trying to prove that a compact set $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$ is closed, by proving that its complement is open. Is the following correct?

Consider an arbitrary $x_{0} \in E^c$. Note that $E\subseteq \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{N}}\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{K}:d(x, x_{0})>\frac{1}{r}\}$. By compactness of $E$, there exists $\{r_{1}, r_{2},...,r_{n}\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $E\subseteq \bigcup_{r\in\{r_{1}, r_{2},...,r_{n}\}}\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{K}:d(x, x_{0})>\frac{1}{r}\}$. WLOG, let $r_{n}:=\max\{r_{1},...,r_{n}\}$. Then, $E\subseteq \bigcup\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{K}:d(x, x_{0})>\frac{1}{r_{n}}\}$. So, $B_{\epsilon}(x_{0})\subset E$, for $\epsilon := \frac{1}{r_{n}}$. Hence, $E$ is closed.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Your proof is fine: just for future reference, an alternative, that works for [Hausdorff spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space) rather than just metric spaces, is to pick, for each $e \in E$, disjoint open sets $A_e$ and $B_e$ such that $e \in A_e$ and $x_0 \in B_e$. Then $E \subseteq A_{e_1} \cup \ldots \cup A_{e_n}$ for some finite set $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\} \subset E$ and then $B_{e_1} \cap \ldots \cap B_{e_n}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ contained in $E^c$.